# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. No other solutions work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with my code. I looked at the other problems regarding this issue and none helped. There is probably many inefficiencies but I am only looking for the solution to this problem.

```
def read_stats():
    name = input("What is the Exact name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for line_read, line in enumerate(name):
                line_read == 0
                lineone = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 1
                linetwo = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 2
                linethree = my_file.readline()

    return lineone,linetwo,linethree

def read_stats_C2():
    name = input("What is the Exact name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for line_read, line in enumerate(name):
                line_read == 0
                linefour = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 1
                linefive = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 2
                linesix = my_file.readline()

    return linefour,linefive,linesix
```

This is from my function file. And this is from my actual program:

```
from Functions import *
yes = ["y","yes","yeah boi!"]
no = ["n","no","nope"]
T = True
create1 = input("Do you want to load a previously made character? ")
create1 = create1.lower()
if create1 in yes:
    lineone,linetwo,linethree = read_stats()

if create1 in no:
    name,strength,skill = make_char_stats_C1()
    filename1 = input("What is the name you gave your file? ")
    filename1 = filename1 + (".txt")
    with open(filename1, mode="r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file_1:
        for line_read, line in enumerate(filename1):
            if line_read == 0:
                lineone = my_file_1.readline()

            elif line_read == 1:
                linetwo = my_file_1.readline()

            elif line_read == 2:
                linethree = my_file_1.readline()


create2 = input("Do you want to load a second previously made character? ")
create2 = create1.lower()
if create2 in yes:
    linefour,linefive,linesix = read_stats_C2()

if create2 in no:
        name2,strength2,skill2 = make_char_stats_C2()
        filename2 = input("What is the name you gave your file? ")
        filename2 = filename2 + (".txt")
        with open(filename2, mode="r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file_2:
            for line_read, line in enumerate(filename1):
                if line_read == 0:
                    linefour = my_file_2.readline()

                elif line_read == 1:
                    linefive = my_file_2.readline()

                elif line_read == 2:
                    linesix = my_file_2.readline()



lineone = lineone.replace("\n",".")
linetwo = linetwo.replace("\n","0")
linethree = linethree.replace("\n","0")
linefour = linefour.replace("\n",".")
linefive = linefive.replace("\n","0")
linesix = linesix.replace("\n","0")

linetwo = int(linetwo)/10
linethree = int(linethree)/10
linefive = int(linefive)/10
linesix = int(linesix)/10


if int(linetwo) > int(linefive):
    strDiff = int(linetwo) - int(linefive)
    strMod = int(strDiff) / 5
    print(strMod)

if int(linetwo) < int(linefive):
    strDiff = int(linefive) - int(linetwo)
    strMod = int(strDiff) / 5
    print(strMod)

if int(linetwo) == int(linefive):
    strMod = int("0")
    print(strMod)

if int(linethree) > int(linesix):
    skillDiff = int(linethree) - int(linesix)
    skillMod = int(skillDiff) / 5
    print(skillMod)

if int(linethree) < int(linesix):
    skillDiff = int(linesix) - int(linethree)
    skillMod = int(skillDiff) / 5
    print(skillMod)

if int(linethree) == int(linesix):
    skillMod = int("0")
    print(skillMod)

value = rolldice(6)
value1 = value
value = rolldice(6)
value2 = value

##if int(value) == int(value2):
##    value = 0
##
##if int(value) < int(value):
##
```

edit: This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Documents\Year 10-11\ICT\Python CA\Task Three.py", line 57, in <module>
  linefive = int(linefive)/10
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

edit - Written it out again to this stage :

edit - Now it just prints many empty strings...:

```
from Functions import *
yes = ["y","yes","yeah boi!"]
no = ["n","no","nope"]
T = True

create1 = input("Do you want to load a previously made character? ")
create1 = create1.lower()
if create1 in yes:
    lineone,linetwo,linethree = read_stats()

elif create1 in no:
    name = input("What is the EXACT name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for i in range(3):
            my_file.readline()

        lineone = my_file.readline()
        linetwo = my_file.readline()
        linethree = my_file.readline()

create2 = input("Do youwant to load a second previously made character? ")
create2 = create2.lower()
if create2 in yes:
    linefour,linefive,linesix = read_stats_C2()
    print(linefive)

if create2 in no:
    name2 = input("What is the EXACT name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name3 = name2 + ".txt"
    with open(name3, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file2:
        for i in range(3):
            my_file.readline()

        linefour = my_file2.readline()
        linefive = my_file2.readline()
        linesix = my_file2.readline()

print(lineone,linetwo,linethree,linefour,linefive,linesix)
```

Comment: Exactly which line is your error appearing on?

Comment: Please do include the *full* traceback when you are asking about a Python exception. Without the information contained therein, you are asking us to guess.

Comment: Clearly `linefive` is an empty string.

Comment: Did you fix your `read_stats*` functions too?

Comment: Fixed it all! Just the way I formatted it, it didnt like.

Answer (score 0):

If you can follow these steps exactly, you will be able to fix your error.

1. Determine exactly which line the error is being thrown on. It should be clear from the stack trace. It will almost certainly be one of the lines with a call to `int()` on it.
2. Use `print` to print out the argument that is being passed to `int()`.
3. Eyeball the output and observe that it does not look like an integer.
4. Fix your code so that it looks like an integer, or realize that you should not have been converting to `int` in the first place.
5. Go back to `1` and iterate until all `int()` related errors are gone.

Based on the editted question, you are trying to convert the empty string `''` to an `int`, which is why you are getting the error.

You should initialize `linefive` to something else, because you cannot convert it `''` to an `int`.

Comment: Well 'linefive' is already assigned to a value, I dont see why it would be an empty string? @merlin2011

Comment: Insert the line `print(linefive)` throughout your code and you will eventually find out where it became an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** want to loop over the characters of the filename:

```
def read_stats_C2():
    name = input("What is the Exact name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for line_read, line in enumerate(name):
                line_read == 0
                linefour = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 1
                linefive = my_file.readline()
                line_read == 2
                linesix = my_file.readline()

    return linefour,linefive,linesix
```

That loops as many times as there are characters in `name`. You are most likely calling `.readline()` too often and hitting the end of the file (at which point `.readline()` returns `''`, the empty string.

**Remove** the loop, and instead skip lines with a separate loop:

```
def read_stats_C2():
    name = input("What is the Exact name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for i in range(3):
            # skip 3 lines
            my_file.readline()

        linefour = my_file.readline()
        linefive = my_file.readline()
        linesix = my_file.readline()

    return linefour,linefive,linesix
```

or better yet, use `itertools.islice` to pick out those 3 lines for you:

```
from itertools import islice

def read_stats_C2():
    name = input("What is the Exact name of the file your character is saved as? ")
    name1 = name + ".txt"
    with open(name1, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        return list(islice(my_file, 3, 6))
```